# Changes to particle problems not showing in 3-D View panel

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, particles, 3d-view, error

I'm using Python to change the positions and sizes of particles in a particle system. The Python code seems to work: when I print the new positions and sizes of particles, they are as expected. However, none of these changes will show in the 3-D view panel.

This is not a simple issue with the visualization not updating automatically upon running the script (which some people have asked about). Even when I take steps to update the visualization (for example, changing from render view to material view and back), none of my changes are evident.

Is there a reason for this—and better yet, is there a way to make sure the changes I make with Python reflect in the model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the current frame.

Comment: You mean the current *animation* frame? Any reason why that would work? Just trying to understand the rationale for the suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Only because thats the time it reads the existing location to calculate its new location. Guessing that viewport refreshing doesn't refresh cached particle data, but changing frame means it needs to get the new position.

Comment: Aha! Thanks! I just learned something worthwhile. Looking forward to giving it a try tomorrow. I've been battling with this model for weeks, and if this works, man, I'll... open a metaphorical bottle of champagne, because I don't keep real bottles around, but the excitement will be real :D

Comment: Bummer. My hopes were up but sadly changing the animation frame has no effect. So strange that my changes reflect in Python but not in the visualization of the model. The new particle positions printed in Python are correct as are the new sizes, yet this is the extent of these changes, apparently. Wondering what else could leave the visualization so stale.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that shows your problem and upload the script and .blend? Then maybe we can help, but I haven't encountered your problem and have no spontaneous solution